# Regular expression to replace empty comma-delimited fields with "NA"

Tags: regex

I have a comma separated list of strings like the one below.

```
a,b   ,c ,d, ,      , , ,e, f,g,h  .
```

I want to write a regular expression that will replace the empty values i.e., strings that contain only white spaces to 'NA'. So the result should be

```
a,b   ,c ,d,NA,NA,NA,NA,e, f,g,h  .
```

I tried using ",\s+," to search but it skips the alternate empty strings and results in

```
a,b   ,c ,d,NA,      ,NA, ,e, f,g,h  .
```

What's the correct regex to use here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(?<=,)\s+(?=,)`

This is a lookbehind for a comma, then whitespace, then a lookahead for a comma

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

`echo a,b   ,c ,d, ,      , , ,e, f,g,h  . | perl -p -e  's/, +[^a-z|A-Z]/,Na/g'`

Or:

`echo a,b   ,c ,d, ,      , , ,e, f,g,h  . | perl -p -e  's/, +\S/,Na/g'`

if you want to make it work with non `a-Z` characters also (thanks for the comment :)

Comment: Nope. You assume all characters would fall into the [a-z] range.